# Why does this not work? echo 'abc' | strings

Tags: linux, bash

I found

```
tcpdump -l -s0 -w - tcp dst port 80 | strings
```

on [this article.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tcpdump-fu?page=0,1) So I want to try to use `strings` command. But command like

```
echo 'abc' | strings
```

does not work. Why? Thanks in advance.

I read the `strings` manual. But got no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character
>   sequences that are at least 4 characters long [...]

Note the 4...

To make it work:

```
echo abc |strings -n 3
```

Comment: = =! Thanks. I should read it more carefully...